# How to make the header full width using Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, header

I know only plain HTML and CSS, now I want to know how to use Bootstrap and and responsive for all devices. Just I copied the CDN from internet.

This is my first site in Bootstrap.

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="logo">
<div id="l1">
<a href="index.php">
<img src="image/logo.png" width="87" height="80"/></a><br/><b style="color:#000;">Triton Exports <br/></div>
<div id="l2">
<p>
<span class="t1">Email : info@tritonexports.com <br/>Mobile:9791900725</span><br/>
</p>
</div>
</div><!--wrapper-->

style.css
#wrapper
{
    width:1000px;
    margin:auto;
    height:auto;
}

#logo
{
    width:1000px;
    height:135px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#FFF;
}

#l1
{
    width:400px;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    padding-left:100px;
    padding-top:10px;

}

#l2
{
    width:300px;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    padding-left:200px;
    line-height:20px;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is simple but responsive nav bar in bootstrap. you can add more things to it.

Bootstrap have plenty of classes to design elements. You do not need to write your own `CSS`. In your project, you are using your own `CSS`.

Visit the official website [getbootstrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com) to learn bootstrap.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```